# Why I am missing the close button using kolkov/ngx-gallery in angular?

Tags: ngx-gallery

I am trying to show the close button when displaying the slideshow of images. I am able to set the following options:

```
`this.galleryOptions = [
      {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        previewCloseOnClick: true,
        previewCloseOnEsc: true,
        thumbnailsColumns: 4,
        imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide
      },
```

I am able to close the slideshow when esc is press or click away from image but there is no close button.

I took the code from the documentation but the close button is not shown.